# Calling colour palette from within another package isn't working

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, palette, colorbrewer

I am using a graphing package CGPfunctions to make interaction graphs. In the vignette, they use a RColorBrewer palette using the following code (copied with my own data in there).

```
plot <- Plot2WayANOVA(formula = MOL ~ x * y, dataframe = scaled, confidence=.95,
          plottype = "line",
          errorbar.display = "SEM",
          xlab = " ",
          ylab = " ",
          title = ggtitle,
          subtitle = NULL,
          offset.style = "wide",
          overlay.type = "none", #box, violin
          posthoc.method = "hsd",
          show.dots = FALSE,
          package = "RColorBrewer",
          palette = "Dark2",
          ggplot.component = theme(text=element_text(size=24))
```

)

However, no colour change results even though RColorBrewer is open, and I haven't deviated from the vignette. Is it something on my end that is preventing the palette from being used?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It looks from the docs that these are the default settings of the function, so you would not expect the colors to change. Perhaps try setting `palette = "Set1"` to see if that changes the colors?

Comment: @AllanCameron, no palette results in changes, Set1, Set3, ggsci palettes, etc.